# Emulator: DmaMap: ERROR: getHostAddr: guest paddr 0x0 not alloced error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start to run the project with virtual device, the error start showing

```
16:49   Emulator: DmaMap: ERROR: getHostAddr: guest paddr 0x0 not alloced!
16:49   Emulator: C:\buildbot\src\android\emu-master-dev\external\qemu\android\android-emugl\host\libs\Translator\GLES_V2\GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexSubImage2D:3458 error 0x502
```

I tried reinstalling my Android Studio, wiping data and delete and reinstalling the virtual device, but nothing works.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get any answer.. then please help me